# How to have infinite path segments using Sinatra

Tags: sinatra

Lets say that I want to have unlimited path segements and have the get multiply them together such that:

```
get "/multiply/num1/num2/num3......" do
    num1 = params[:num1].to_i
    num2 = params[:num2].to_i
    .... 
    solution = num1 * num2 * ....
    "the solution is = #{solution}"
end
```

I want the user to be able to type out as many path segments as they want and then get the solution for those numbers multiplied together.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do it:

```
get "/multiply/*" do
    n = params[:splat][0].split('/')
    for i in (0...n.length)
        n[i] = n[i].to_f
    end

    n = n.inject{ |sum, n| sum * n }
    "solution = #{n}"
end
```

Comment: Comes in handy for accessing files in directories.

Comment: You can also simplify to `get '/multiply/*' do |nums]` and then `nums.split('/')`.